# Is there a quick and easy way to dump the contents of a MacOS X keychain?

Tags: macos, applescript, keychain

I'm looking for a way to dump (export) the contents of an OS X keychain into a file that I can easily process elsewhere, such as tab-delimited plaintext or something of the sort.

The Keychain Access app does not offer any such functionality, and getting a key's data involves opening each in turn, and having to type in the keychain's password to see the password stored with the key, every time.

After a bit of digging, I found somebody's solution by using AppleScript and the Keychain Scripting app to access keychains (can't link to individual post; scroll down about two thirds to the end of the page):

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1398759

Using Keychain scripting, you can access all data fields of all the keys – including the plaintext password! – and it's fairly easy to dump this data into a text file etc. I've tested it and it works well.

However, this solution still involves having to confirm access to each key by clicking OK on a dialog. This is much better than having to type in the keychain's password every time, but it's still irritating. Furthermore, you have to confirm access twice for each key; once for Script Editor (or the script itself if it's running as an app) and once for Keychain Scripting. So, if you're processing a keychain with 100 keys, you have to manually click OK on 200 dialogs.

I'm now looking for a solution to get around this. I realize that as it's the purpose of keychains to safeguard the sensitive data and prevent precisely the kind of thing I'm trying to do, any such solution would probably involve some kind of hack.

I'd be very interested in your ideas!

Answer (score 37):

Allright, I'm stupid. There's a command-line tool called `security` that does just this (and lots of other actions on keychains).

An example usage:

```
security dump-keychain -d login.keychain
```

This will dump all the data in the login.keychain (the default keychain for a user) as plaintext, including the passwords. You **still** have to confirm access , but only once for each key, and it's much faster than (and doesn't throw weird errors when trying to access certain fields) using AppleScript. And it's no hack.

Without the `-d` option, it will dump all the fields except for the password.

The dumped data for a key looks like this (for an internet key; program keys and certificates have other fields, but the format is the same):

```
keychain: "/Users/<username>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="tech.slashdot.org (<username for this web login>)"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="<username for this web login>"
    "atyp"<blob>="form"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303038303432333038323730355A00  "20080423082705Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>=<NULL>
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>="Kennwort des Web-Formulars"
    "icmt"<blob>="default"
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303038303432333038323730355A00  "20080423082705Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>=<NULL>
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000 
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>="http"
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="tech.slashdot.org"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
data:
"<the plaintext password for this key>"
```

Comment: Is there any magic way to avoid clicking "Always Allow" once for each entry?

Comment: @Cliff You can find the AppleScript that will press the buttons for you here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/137336.

Comment: For the iCloud keychain, which the (10.9.5) `security` tool doesn't see, you can copy everything from the iCloud keychain to a new keychain and still use this technique.  (http://selfsuperinit.com/2014/01/20/exporting-icloud-keychain-passwords-as-a-plain-text-file/)

Answer (score 15):

**Please read this:** https://gist.github.com/rmondello/b933231b1fcc83a7db0b

Ignore:-----

I found a sollution to the "Always Allow" dialog in each key!

Just run the previous command with sudo.

```
sudo security dump-keychain -d login.keychain
```

This way you'll only need to enter your password two times. One on the Terminal to sudo and another to unlock the keychain! ;)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Does not seem to work, it still asks me to "allow/deny" each item. Maybe you had "always allowed" everything the first time you ran the command? The second time it would appear to have just magically worked (regardless of the sudo).

Comment: I just pressed allow 250 times.

Comment: In High Sierra, running with sudo still prompts for password on every key.  Copying from iCloud to a local keychain also requires the password for every key.

Answer (score 0):

Update, there is now a tool that does this nicely:

> Keychaindump is a proof-of-concept tool for reading OS X keychain passwords as root. It hunts for unlocked keychain master keys located in the memory space of the securityd process, and uses them to decrypt keychain files.

Source: https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump

Comment: This git project is abandon-ware, last commit 6 years ago.  
Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was just looking for the same:
Modified applescript from github somebody posted. To be run in ScriptEditor and must be allowed in Preferences & Security.

```
set keychainPassword to "yourpasswordgoeshere"

tell application "System Events"
    repeat while exists (processes where name is "SecurityAgent")
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            delay 0.1
            try
                set value of text field 1 of window 1 to keychainPassword
                click button "Allow" of window 1
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

You must click each window separetly in order to activate them. For that I used tool "murgaa auto clicker" I had known from runescape many years ago (http://www.murgaa.com/auto-clicker-mac/ seems still active). You just set shortcut for autoclicking (eg. Command+R) and set timer to 10ms and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

## [Keysafe](https://miln.eu/keysafe/)

> Keysafe reads and decrypts Apple Keychain files. Use Keysafe to securely access your passwords and credentials without a Mac.

I wrote a tool called Keysafe to extract the contents of Keychain files. The tool is available on Mac, Windows, and Linux.

Keysafe is not free; a licence is required to fully decrypt a Keychain. Without a licence the contents are still extracted but the decrypted values are partially redacted and secure notes are not post-processed into RTFD files.

If you have a Keychain that does not "just work" with Keysafe, please get in touch. The Keychain format is expansive and finding edge cases is always interesting.

Answer (score -3):

I found solution for not clicking "Allow" multiple times

```
sudo su
security dump-keychain -d /Users/YourUsername/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```