# macos security dump-keychain enoding

Tags: macos, character-encoding, keychain

I am trying to write a password exporter for the mac keychain and am using `security dump-keychain -d login.keychain` that is explained in [questions 717095](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717095/is-there-a-quick-and-easy-way-to-dump-the-contents-of-a-macos-x-keychain). However, I cannot figure out what character encoding the blob data has.

Examples:

- \134 [REVERSE SOLIDUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005c/charset_support.htm)
- \303\251 [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm)

What character encoding is being used here?

Edit: You can use `security dump-keychain | grep "\\\\"` to see examples more examples of the format.

Answer (score 1):

The output format for `security dump-keychain -d login.keychain` uses octal format instead of hex or decimal.

The codes then map to the utf-8 character encoding format.